# What is the purpose of this bitwise operation? (mWidth + 0x0000000F) & ~0x0000000F;

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Here is the line of code I'm confused at:

```
 mMaskRowBytes = (mWidth + 0x0000000F) & ~0x0000000F;
```

~ is the `NOT` operator right?

Let's say `mWidth` is 960, or 1111000000

So what we get here is

```
00000000000000000000001111001111 
&
11111111111111111111111111110000
```

which would just result in

```
00000000000000000000001111000000
```

Right?

Is the purpose to convert a decimal number into a binary number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ~ operator takes the complement:

So for example: 0110 would become 1001

What the purpose is I'm not sure - you'd need to show how mMaskRowBytes is being used. **But it looks as if it is being used for something that deals in 16bit (2bytes) chunks and therefore needs to ensure data is being aligned to the nearest 2byte address space**. Often a compiler will do this to ensure the most efficient stack alignment. On 32bit systems this would be 4bytes and 64bit 4/8bytes. This means the compiler can then be confident to move the stack up and down by efficient steps. For modern OS this is all taken care-off by the compiler and the OS. If you're down at the system level then you might have to do this all for yourself.

Comment: I'm working with images here, so it looks like the memory needs to be aligned because OS X?  not 100%

Comment: Ah right this could be to do with padding. Are you reading/writing/formatting image data. Some formats need things padded out to certain multiples on a row by row basis? If so don't get too hung up on the details. There should be some libraries out there to save you the bother.

Answer (score 2):

'~' is the *bitwise complementation* operator.

For positive `mWidth`, all it does is round upwards to the next number that is a multiple of 16. (Since 960 already divides 16, it remains unchanged).

There are clearer ways of doing that, although the specifics would be down to your particular language.